# Assertion in non-test function in Go

Tags: go, assert

I want to use assertion in a function, but it is not a test function. It is just a normal function, and I want to use something like `assert.Equal(param1, some_constant)`. I came across the following package: https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert
Though, it appears that it also requires the `testing` package, and to give to a function a parameter of type `*testing.T`. Is there any other assert function in Go, where I can directly call the `assert` function without actually relying on any other testing package or parameter?

Comment: If you really want this: Why not write your own assert function? Why rely on external packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go does not provide assertions. There is a section in the language FAQ from the Go team here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions
If you really into it, you can just write a normal function that accepts two values and does something if they evaluate to equal or not equal, as you desire.