# How to call `assert` functions from non-test function?

Tags: go

This question is similar to [Assertion in non-test function in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683134/assertion-in-non-test-function-in-go) but I really do want to call `assert.ElementsMatch` from a non-test function.

How do I go about instantiating a `testing.T` object?

This function will eventually be called from `main` which uses flags for configuration so it can't just be a test.

Context: We're performing a data migration from some source databases to a destination database. The first part of the migration is to copy data from the source into a holding table in the destination. The second part (and here's where `assert.ElementsMatch` plays a role) is to see how the holding tables and general use tables differ — we want to try to catch unforeseen scenarios with the data migration (eg perhaps some date's format is different or the wrong id number was copied). The third part is, once the holding table data has been vetted, to copy that into the general use tables. This all sounds a bit overly complicated but that could be because both source databases and destination general use databases are currently being used.

Comment: You can simply use `reflect.DeepEqual`

Comment: I want to call `assert.ElementsMatch` so I don't have to recode everything that it does.

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks! If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Note that at rutime you will pay the price of formatting an error message to just throw it away should the call return `false`. I mean, this approach is OK (and even neat) for a throw-away hack, but certainly not for a production code.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using it for an ad hoc script and it's the error message that `assert` produces that I want.

Comment: I've added some context to the question which may explain why the use of `assert` actually makes sense in this scenario even if it wouldn't be advised in most other scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an instance of `testing.T`.

The [`assert.ElementsMatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#ElementsMatch) function takes [`assert.TestingT`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#TestingT) as its argument, which is an interface with a single method. So you can simply define a custom implementation of that interface that does whatever you like with that method and pass an instance of that custom implementation to `assert.ElementsMatch`.

For example:

```golang
type testingT struct{}

func (testingT) Errorf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(format, args...)
}

// ...

t := new(testingT)
if assert.ElementsMatch(t, listA, listB) {
    // ...
}
```